# Check if xsl:attribute name is valid for XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

In my data it's possible that there are one or more processing-instructions which are used to give that specific block of content new attributes or overwrite the values of existing ones.

The way I do this requires it that the name of the PIs are valid xsl attribute names.

The Question: Is it possible to check within the xsl-stylesheet if the name of the PI is an actual valid (=allowed as `<xsl:attribute name="*thisname*">` in XSL-FO) attribute name?

```html
<xsl:if test="./processing-instruction()"> <!-- add condition to test for valid name? -->
    <xsl:for-each select="./processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:variable name="pi_name"><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:attribute name="{$pi_name}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding this problem: [Check if xsl:attribute name is valid for XSL-FO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395757/check-if-xslattribute-name-is-valid-for-xsl-fo/57408678?noredirect=1#comment101311318_57408678)

That's the code I use derived from Tony's solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template name="handle_block_attribute">
        <xsl:variable name="attributes" select="document('PATH\attributelist.xml')//attributelist/attribute"/>

        <xsl:if test=".//processing-instruction()">
            <xsl:for-each select=".//processing-instruction()">
                <xsl:variable name="pi_name"><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$pi_name = $attributes">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{$pi_name}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <fo:inline color="red">Invalid attribute-name in PI: <xsl:value-of select="$pi_name" /></fo:inline><fo:block />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template is called in this way:

```
<xsl:template match="para">
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="para.standard">
        <xsl:call-template name="handle_block_attribute" />
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

And that's the data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<book>
    <sect class="hierarchic" type="chapter">
        <para class="heading" style="Chapter">
            <inline style="HeadingText">HD</inline>
        </para>
        <para style="Standard">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer eleifend consequat pede Aenean est. <?font-size 13pt?><?fotn-family Arial?><?color green?><?fline-height 3pt?></para>
        <para style="Standard">Consequat semper tortor id convallis leo Phasellus eget non sagittis neque.</para>
    </sect>
</book>
```

**EDIT2:**

Well, maybe there is a more elegant way, but it works: I'm going with two for-each-loops, one for the correct PIs and after that another one for the flawed ones including error-output.

```
<xsl:if test=".//processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:variable name="pi_name"><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="$pi_name = $attributes">
            <xsl:attribute name="{$pi_name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select=".//processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:variable name="pi_name"><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="not($pi_name = $attributes)">
            <fo:inline color="red">Invalid attribute name in PI: <xsl:value-of select="$pi_name" /></fo:inline><fo:block />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Aren't both processing instruction names and attributes names of the same data type anyway?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow!  It might help your question get more attention if you show us what you have tried and what output you get.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Attribute defines attributes and https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-PITarget defines processing instructions, in both https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name is used. I am not sure which cases you expect where you could have a processing instruction name not being a possible attribute name.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Hi Martin, e.g. when there's the PI <?font-size 7pt?> all is fine. But when it says <?fotn-size 7pt?> the PI name is not a valid xsl attribute name and the formatter gives an error (unknown property).

Comment: @geekzster What I tried was research and reading, because I don't even know how to start to do this kind of check. :D I could put a list of allowed attribute names somewhere, of course, and test against this list. But I was hoping for a more elegant way or a function like function-available().

Comment: @AlphaZen `fotn-size` is a valid attribute name...

Comment: @Alejandro For an xsl-attribute?

Comment: What kind of "formatter" are you talking about? If the question is about a particular XML document type like XSL-FO then add that to the question. In terms of XML and XSLT in general you can of course create an attribute named `fotn-size`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sorry for being unprecise. Yes, the whole question relates to XSL-FO. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made it harder than necessary for yourself by using XSLT 1.0 instead of either XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0 simply because it's harder to construct a list of property names to compare against.  With the later versions, you could just make a sequence of strings.  With XSLT 1.0, the simplest way (that I can remember) is to put each property name as the value of a separate element and then compare the prospective property name against the selected set of elements.  The magic of XPath's `=` is that it is true if any value of one side matches any value on the other side.

You can extract the definitive list of XSL-FO property names by processing the XML source for the XSL specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xsl11-20061205/xslspec.xml

With this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:local="uuid:503f6e96-fda1-4464-98b6-a60dbecc5946"
    exclude-result-prefixes="local">

    <properties xmlns="uuid:503f6e96-fda1-4464-98b6-a60dbecc5946">
        <property>font-size</property>
        <property>font-weight</property>
    </properties>

    <xsl:variable name="properties" select="document('')/*/local:properties/local:property"/>
    <xsl:template match="fo:*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:for-each select="processing-instruction()">
                <xsl:variable name="pi_name" select="local-name()" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$pi_name = $properties">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{$pi_name}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:message>Unrecognised property: <xsl:value-of select="$pi_name"
                             /></xsl:message>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this document:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:block><?font-size 16pt?><?font-weight bold?></fo:block>
    <fo:block><?fotn-size 16pt?><?bogus bold?></fo:block>
</fo:root>
```

generates this:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:block font-size="16pt" font-weight="bold"/>
  <fo:block/>
</fo:root>
```

plus messages about 'fotn-size' and 'bogus'.

I put the property names in the stylesheet to make it easier to test.  You could put the XML in an external document and not have to fuss with the `local` namespace.  The namespace was necessary because the only non-XSLT elements allowed at the top level of an XSLT stylesheet have to be in a non-XSLT namespace.

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for that. Sadly I have no choice but to work with XSLT 1.0. I already guessed I have to test against a list, I just hoped for a neat trick or function I've overseen. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: There is smth I don't understand: Several correct named PIs in the data work fine. Still ok if the flawed PIs occure behind the correct ones. But when flawed and correct PIs are mixed up, only the leading correct PIs "become" attributes. All correct PIs after the first flawed PI get lost, but for every flawed PI there's a message (written into the data via inline-tags). Could that happen because I don't use the "copy" and "copy-of" elements? It's rather `<xsl:template match="x"><xsl:call-template name="y" /><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:template>` (only "properties"-var and for-each loop in y).

Comment: @AlphaZen That's because the way attributes are serialized. You first need to output every allowed attribute and after that output the error messages for the forbiden attributes.

Comment: The code that I posted works okay with any sequence of PIs.  I'm afraid that I don't quite understand your description of how your code works or why it's behaving as you describe.  Can you add your current code to the question or start a new question?

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I know what I did wrong. The error output has to happen after the for-each when using elements containing content. Already made that mistake years ago, should have known better. :D I'll start to rework that part and update later.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin Honnen has [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395757/check-if-xslattribute-name-is-valid#comment101273680_57395757), PI target and attributes names must conform the [Name production of XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name). Thus, the only case when this might conflict is when a PI target could be interpreted as a QName and the prefix does not match an in scope namespace binding.

Because of that, `:` is not allowed in PI target.

Here is the errors given by different XSLT processor when parsing the input source:

```
<?a:b 7pt?>
<root/>
```

Saxon:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: urn:from-string; lineNumber:
>   1; columnNumber: 6; A colon is not allowed in the name 'a:b' when
>   namespaces are enabled.

MSXML:

> Input parsing error: Entity names, PI targets, notation names and
>   attribute values declared to be of types ID, IDREF(S), ENTITY(IES) or
>   NOTATION cannot contain any colons. , 1:7, `<?a:b 7pt?>`

**Edit**: about `<?fotn-size 7pt?>`, this stylesheet following your example

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:if test="./processing-instruction()">
                <xsl:for-each select="./processing-instruction()">
                    <xsl:variable name="pi_name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:attribute name="{$pi_name}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<?fotn-size 7pt?>
<root/>
```

Output:

```
<root fotn-size="7pt"/>
```

Comment: Ok, sorry, I think I used the term "valid" in the wrong way. Maybe "allowed" would have been better? While something like `fotn-size` is technically valid for xml, its not an allowed attribute name in xsl. Or am I completely wrong?